# Android MD2 hash

Tags: android, encryption, hash

I need to encript a string with MD2 algorithm. But Android doesn't include this method. If you try to use it with MessageDigest.getInstance("MD2"), it throws a NoSuchAlgorithmException exception. Is there any easy way to use MD2 encryption in android?

Answer (score 0):

Give [spongycastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle) a shot. MD2 is broken btw, do not use it for new apps (use sha256)